# Read SMS ,generate hit and then delete programatically

Tags: android, eclipse

Using broadcast receiver it's execute perfectly.

Comment: Still not posted the complete code ..deleteSMS() is called where when ? .... and it is meant for deleting all the sms :)

Comment: I've call delete sms method in on post execute method.. yes it's delete all the sms from inbox, actually i think i need to delete only read sms but i don't konw how can i do it..also i have update it

Comment: Do it by storing the value of read sms body to sharedpreference and delete only those who are in sharedprefrence.

Comment: @maven , can you please give example, I've save values in shared preference but i don't know how can i compare it.

Comment: Is I'm correct?   if(no.equals(Uri.parse(uri)))
 {
 count =getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),null, null);
        }  where in no my shared preference values are stored..

Comment: update your latest code in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Android SMS programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically)

Answer (score -1):

Add permissions in manifest file like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Then Add Intent Filter:

```
<receiver android:name="com.aquadeals.seller.services.SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

Get all SMS:

```
TelephonyProvider telephonyProvider = new TelephonyProvider(context);
List<Sms> smses = telephonyProvider.getSms(Filter.ALL).getList();
```

---

Deleting SMS:

Do it by storing the value of read sms body to sharedpreference and delete only those who are in sharedprefrence.

```
Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
int count = 0;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(inboxUri , null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
       // uri.
        count =getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

[image]

All Android content providers like: Contacts, Call logs, Calendar, ... [Full doc with all options](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022021217/http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging)

Comment: I've already added all the permissions related to read sms , write sms , internate access and also access phone state..

Comment: @Zilu where is your brodcast receiver ? post complete code.. then I may help you